# how to clear text of entry grid tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

tkinter window

[image]

```
rows = []
for i in range(5):
    cols = []
    for j in range(1):

        e = Entry(relief=RIDGE)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=NSEW)
        e.insert(END, '%d.%d' % (i, j))
        cols.append(e)
    rows.append(cols)
```

its not working :-

```
    def onButtonClick():
    for i in range(1):
        for j in range(5):
            e.delete(0.0,END)
```

how to clear text of all Entries onButtonClick()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate over the rows and columns, which is where you're storing the reference to each entry widget:

```
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        col.delete(0, "end")
```

By the way, entry widget indexes are integers, not floating point numbers.

Comment: @SumitRawat: then you did it wrong. It absolutely will work. It must work, because the entries are indeed stored in `rows`, and the `delete` method is indeed how you clear an entry widget. Most likely your actual code has `rows` as a local variable instead of a global or instance variable. It's hard to know since you didn't post a complete program.

Comment: it worked ... thank you very much.. actually i didnt use **<>**  these while binding. Now its working .